# Getting 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/struts/action/ActionServlet.findMapping(Ljava/lang/String;);' error

Tags: java, apache, websphere, struts1

Recently we migrated our application form `Websphere 6.1 to 8.5` and `Java 1.5 to 1.7.` Deployed the ear file and created the RMIC and copied the stubs and skeleton files into respective projects. After starting the server, tried to load the application and getting the below error:

> [6/23/16 3:31:31:759 CDT] 000000dc ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet retail: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/struts/action/ActionServlet.findMapping(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/struts/action/ActionMapping;
>       at com.s1.web.bankcommon.action.CustomRequestProcessor.processPath(Unknown Source)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.action.CustomRequestProcessor.process(CustomRequestProcessor.java:431)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.action.CustomActionServlet.process(CustomActionServlet.java:195)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.action.CustomActionServlet.postFilter(CustomActionServlet.java:236)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filter.ServletChainLink.doFilter(ServletChainLink.java:23)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filter.Filtering.filter(Filtering.java:87)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.action.CustomActionServlet.service(CustomActionServlet.java:226)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>       at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
>       at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
>       at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
>       at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>       at com.s1.web.bb.filters.LogAggFilter.doFilter(LogAggFilter.java:385)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.pso.common.filter.PSOCommonSessionMaintainFilter.doFilter(PSOCommonSessionMaintainFilter.java:291)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.web.bankcommon.filters.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:101)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.web.common.filters.CommonFilterBase.doFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.web.bankcommon.filters.CrossSiteScriptFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.ApplicationFilter.doFilterBody(ApplicationFilter.java:116)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.ApplicationFilter.doFilter(ApplicationFilter.java:83)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.security.session.management.SingleSessionFilter.doFilter(SingleSessionFilter.java:59)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.AbstractFilter.doFilterBody(AbstractFilter.java:60)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:43)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.AbstractFilter.doFilterBody(AbstractFilter.java:60)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:43)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.AbstractThreadContextFilter.doFilterBody(AbstractThreadContextFilter.java:64)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.AbstractThreadContextFilter.doFilter(AbstractThreadContextFilter.java:47)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.security.ui.CachedPrincipalFilter.doFilter(CachedPrincipalFilter.java:60)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.security.ui.websphere.LTPASyncFilter.doFilter(LTPASyncFilter.java:100)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.SetSessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SetSessionTimeoutFilter.java:90)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.s1.arch.ui.filters.RoundTripTraceFilter.doFilter(RoundTripTraceFilter.java:159)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3926)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)

Comment: What's your struts-version? Most likely websphere has something newer without the `findMapping()`-method. So changing your classloading to parent-last should help.

Comment: Did you upgrade your struts too ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.